# Adding employee id to claims in azure AD, Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy is giving does not exist error for service principal id

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping)

I've reached these instructions:

> Assign the policy to your service principal. You also need to get the ObjectId of your service principal.

> To see all your organization's service principals, you can query the Microsoft Graph API. Or, in Microsoft Graph Explorer, sign in to your Azure AD account.

> When you have the ObjectId of your service principal, run the following command:
> PowerShell

`Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the ServicePrincipal> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the Policy>`

So, getting the service principal ID is very unclear, I went to my Azure AD, clicked App Registrations, clicked my Application, this has Application ID, Object ID and Tenant ID, but according some instructions online I should click the "Managed application in..." on the right, which takes me to the Application | Overview page, then the Object Id there is the one I need.

However it does not work. I tried several IDs actually from various pages, but all presented me with this error:

```
C:\temp> Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id guid -RefObjectId otherguid
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy : Error occurred while executing AddServicePrincipalPolicy
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource 'guid' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property
objects are not present.
InnerError:
  RequestId: yetanotherguid
  DateTimeStamp: Fri, 16 Sep 2022 09:45:14 GMT
HttpStatusCode: NotFound
HttpStatusDescription: Not Found
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id guid ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.Add
   ServicePrincipalPolicy
```

Can anyone advise what to do? I thought perhaps I'd be able to get the ID from a powershell command, I tried `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` which gave me a giant list but I couldn't see anything on there that looked like my application.

Comment: I ran the command `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true >c:\temp\principals.txt` which lists many pages of them, however the ObjectId you're suggesting is not in the list, nor is anything with a name that matches or resembles my application. What do you think might have gone wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear, I can understand the pain, went through it recently. Question - how are you creating the Azure AD app (Azure Portal or PowerShell)?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if you are giving Azure AD Application **`Object_ID`**.

***To resolve the error, include the **`Object_ID`** of the Azure Enterprise Application (Service Principal).***

Please **note** that, Enterprise Applications are list of Service Principals.

**You can find your Service Principal `Object ID` like below:**

**Go to Enterprise Application -> Find your App Name -> Object_ID**

[image]

*From the **PowerShell**, you can get the Service Principal `Object ID` like below:*

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true -SearchString test_app
```

[image]

***I am able to add policy to the Service Principal by providing its `Object_ID` successfully like below:***

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the ServicePrincipal> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the Policy>

Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id PolicyID
```

**Response:**

[image]

Please **note** that, If you are creating Azure AD Application via `Azure PowerShell/CLI` Service Principal won't be created.
You have to create Application in **Azure Portal** manually to get the Service Principal created automatically.

Comment: thank you that powershell was key to finding the object id I needed :)